# Use userform to search for unique identifier and update

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have information entered into a spreadsheet using a user form, each row has a unique user id and a bunch of data and pre-labeled empty columns for future updated information.

I have created another user form that I want to use to update empty columns in the rows as required.  I want to be able to enter the unique id into a text box and updated information to populate blank columns into other relevant text boxes and when I hit edit it searches for the relevant unique id and puts the information into the relevant columns of that row.

I do have the clear and close buttons working.

[update form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYig4.png).

This is my sample spreadsheet, with empty columns to be populated when updating

[sample spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9pHM.png)

And the information currently entered into the spreadsheet is entered by this user form.

[enter information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gLHY.png)

I had previously found something like this on this site, but now cannot find it.

I am super new to this and would not know where to start to create my own cod

Comment: Take the id and use `Application.Match()` to find the corresponding row on the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Add here the excel sheet sample to see the table structure. The userform for updating records is in the same sheet as the data?

Comment: Yes, it enters into a sheet and there is a button that generates the update user form.